# Probability (random uniformly)

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

The numbers 1 to 9 are arranged in a line (uniformly at random). What is the >probability that the first number is at least 5 and the last number is at most 3?

My answer to this question is 5/27 because the probability for the first number to be at least 5 is 5/9 and for the probability of the last number to be at most 3 is 3/9.

> $\left(\frac{5}{9}\right)\times\left(\frac{3}{9}\right)$ = $\left(\frac{5}{27}\right)$

But I am also thinking is it possible for the answer to be 5/24.

> $\left(\frac{5\times 3\times 7!}{9!}\right)$

I am confused which is the correct answer to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events are not independent, so we cannot simply multiply their probabilities.

For instance, consider ordering the numbers $1,2$ in a line. What is the probability that the first number is $1$ and the second number is $1$? Well, each of the events has probability $1/2$, so your reasoning shows that the probability is $\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$. That is, there's a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance that the lineup is $11$. But this is impossible! It must be either $12$ or $21$.

Your latter calculation is correct, and $5/24$ is the right answer.

Another way of reaching the answer $5/24$ is to use *conditional* probability. The probability that the first number is $\ge 5$ is $5/9$. *Given* that the first number is $\ge 5$, there are now $8$ numbers to choose from for the last position, and $3$ of them are at most $3$ (as $1,2,3$ are not $\ge 5$). So the probability that the last number is chosen appropriately is $3/8$. These probabilities multiply to give $5/24$.

Comment: So, can I understand it as I can only multiply the probability of the events when the events are independent?

Comment: @AlanBish Yes, indeed. This is actually a specific case of the general rule that you can multiply conditional probabilities ($P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B|A)$), because independence makes the conditionality irrelevant ($P(B|A)=P(B)$).

Comment: Alright, thank you so much!